# "To hold a grudge" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, verbs, word-request

How does one say "to hold a grudge against someone" in Latin? A [grudge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grudge) is "a feeling of deep-seated resentment or ill will".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can resort to Leviticus 19:18. (*Do not seek revenge or bear a grudge against anyone among your people,*). Both (which occurs much less often than one would think) the Vulgate and [Castellio](https://books.google.com/books?id=1d5UAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA2-PA116&lpg=RA2-PA116&dq=%22Populares%20tuos%20ne%22&source=bl&ots=D-NJ2NL1V7&sig=ACfU3U3g5fyINqTTi-7MJaFPXhHpMWmuvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOz6rrv7nzAhXLDewKHR5wBEUQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Populares%20tuos%20ne%22&f=false), use the same formula:

> nec memor eris injuriae civium tuorum (Vulgate)

> neve acceptae ab eis [popularibus] iniuriae memor esto (Castellio)

This is quite interesting choice, for the original text does not mention any "injuiriae" explicitly (nor we can see this in other English translations). This suggestive, I believe, that there is no single word that displays strong-conclusive match for "hold a grudge". At any case, *memor acceptae injuriae* is classical (saw about 3 occurrences); and there are many instances of *accepta iniuria*, here is one from Cicero that suggest *dolere iniuriā acceptā*:

> quod mihi non modo irasci gravissima **iniuria accepta** sed ne **dolere** quidem impune licet (because I cannot indulge my anger at so deadly an injury or even my bitterness with impunity (Loeb)).